# Before save validation not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a concern that checks addresses and zip codes with the intention of returning an error if the zip code does not match the state that is inputed. I also don't want the zip code to save unless the problem gets fixed.

The problem that I am having is that it appears that the if I submit the form, the error message in create pops up and I am not able to go through to the next page, but then somehow the default zip code is still saved. This only happens on `edit`. The validations are working on new.

I don't know if I need to share my controller, if I do let me know and I certainly will.

In my model I just have a

```
include StateMatchesZipCodeConcern

before_save :verify_zip_matches_state
```

Here is my concern

```
module StateMatchesZipCodeConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def verify_zip_matches_state
    return unless zip.present? && state.present?

    state_search_result = query_zip_code

    unless state_search_result.nil?
      return if state_search_result.upcase == state.upcase
      return if validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes
    end
    errors[:base] << "Please verify the address you've submitted. The postal code #{zip.upcase} is not valid for the state of #{state.upcase}"
    false
  end

  private

  def query_zip_code
    tries ||= 3
    Geocoder.search(zip).map(&:state_code).keep_if { |x| Address::STATES.values.include?(x) }.first
  rescue Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError, Timeout::Error
    retry unless (tries -= 1).zero?
  end

  def validate_against_multi_state_zip_codes
    ::Address::MULTI_STATE_ZIP_CODES[zip].try(:include?, state)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a `before_save` for validations? Wouldn't a validation be more suitable?

Comment: OK, so i've used both `before_save` and also `validation`.   They both work well enough on `new`, but the error is still having problems in the `edit` side of things.  Won't allow the user to continue, but zip code is still changed.

Comment: Do you have any other callback setting defaults values or running before this : verify_zip_matches_state ?

Comment: @JuanMatias I do not.